# sed match pattern with multi line string in a variable

Tags: regex, bash, ubuntu, sed, ubuntu-16.04

I read a lot of answers and examples but couldn't found a matching example as I couldn't find for sed too. Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
sftp_configuration_lines="Match User ${sftp_username}
ForceCommand internal-sftp
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChrootDirectory /home/${sftp_username}
PermitTunnel no
AllowAgentForwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no

"

    sed -i -e "s|${sftp_configuration_lines_sed}|#removed|g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config;
```

Of course this one is not working and giving an unterminated command error.

I have tried it with \ in the line endings and also with \n but still no luck. What am I missing here ?

Comment: Hello @Edvin, thank you for your kind comment but I didn't used single quote anywhere and you can use different delimeters like /,#,| as long as they are in the right order.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `sed`, you can use `awk` with an empty `RS`:

```
sftp_configuration_lines="Match User ${sftp_username}
ForceCommand internal-sftp
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChrootDirectory /home/${sftp_username}
PermitTunnel no
AllowAgentForwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no"

awk -v RS= -v s="$sftp_configuration_lines" '{gsub(s, "#removed")} 1' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

**Alternatively**, you can also use `perl`:

```
perl -0777 -pe "s~$sftp_configuration_lines~#removed~" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Comment: I am not sure why but not working. Could there be something missing ?

Comment: See my updated, how to set `sftp_configuration_lines`. Make sure you have exact same text in `sshd_config` Otherwise try my `perl` solution.

Comment: still not working. I decided to go with an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

Does this kind of approach suffice for you? In this case you just iterate through your patterns and remove line by line.

```
 declare -a patterns=( "Match User ${sftp_username}" "ForceCommand internal-sftp" "PasswordAuthentication yes" "ChrootDirectory /home/${sftp_username}" "PermitTunnel no" "AllowAgentForwarding no" "AllowTcpForwarding no" "X11Forwarding no" );

 for pattern in "${patterns[@]}"
 do
     sed -i  -e "s|${pattern}|#removed|g"  /etc/ssh/sshd_config;

 done
```

Hope this helps to solve your problem.

Greetings!

#### Note : Im assuming you have something inside "$sftp_username", in case you dont and you are actually trying to replace the literal string just change the " for ' in the array declaration as such :

```
  declare -a patterns=( 'Match User ${sftp_username}' "ForceCommand internal-sftp" "PasswordAuthentication yes" 'ChrootDirectory /home/${sftp_username}' "PermitTunnel no" "AllowAgentForwarding no" "AllowTcpForwarding no" "X11Forwarding no" );
```